# I can use GET from my test JSON server, but cannot use PUT or POST

Tags: json, rest, http, http-put

This is my testing server: https://my-json-server.typicode.com/EmreYavuzalp/jsonTestEtmeAraci

I can get the contents of the employees from here. With this:

```
curl -XGET 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/EmreYavuzalp/jsonTestEtmeAraci/employees'
```

But cannot do the PUT at all. Neither POST. I tried it both ways. It just shows {} (empty brackets), not even an error code. What would that mean? I use this code to put:

```
curl -X PUT https://my-json-server.typicode.com/EmreYavuzalp/jsonTestEtmeAraci/employees/ \
-d '{"employees":[
  { "firstName":"Emre", "lastName":"Emre" }
]}'
```

I tried to remove "employees" and send it that way:

```
curl -X PUT https://my-json-server.typicode.com/EmreYavuzalp/jsonTestEtmeAraci \
-d '{
"firstName": "Emre",
"lastName": "Emre"
}'
```

And if I do POST, it says

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Still doesn't work. What could be wrong here? It doesn't return any error code.

Comment: You should give the objects an unique id and then operate on those ids by making requests to /employees/1 to change/delete and employee with an id of 1 for example.

Comment: I tried 
    curl -DELETE 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/EmreYavuzalp/jsonTestEtmeAraci/employees/1'

But that didn't work for example.

Comment: You need to give the employees an id in your JSON such as 
`{"id": 1, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}`

Comment: Ok I did that, it seems to work. But when I do GET request again, datas I sent aren't there.

Comment: It returns 200 error code, it means OK: But that sent data not shown when I do GET request. I just created a simple web server on my pc, I sent there but still doesn't work.